# Formulas in pictures won't update when screenupdating is off

Tags: image, vba, excel, camera, formulas

I am using formulas for pictures in my Excel sheet. For example, I have a picture called "Picture 15" and I made the formula `=$B$20:$E$29` assigned to that picture. The problem is, when `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, the formula doesn't update. As soon as `ScreenUpdating` becomes `True`, the formula is updated.

Comment: If you toggle ScreenUpdating it may refresh.  What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I want the picture to be automatically changed without turning on the screenupdating.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context?  Typically you turn off ScreenUpdating if *you don't want to see screen updates*, so it's not clear from your question why you have it turned off.

Comment: My code is something like this: 1) Application.ScreenUpdating = False 2) copy some values from somewhere and paste it in the range B20:E29 , 3) print the picture 15 (the formula of picture 15 is "=$B$20:$E$29") , 4) Application.ScreenUpdating = True. The problem is that the picture 15 doesn't change as the codes change the range B20:E29. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So don't turn off screenupdating, or turn it on before printing the picture?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I don't want the user to see the screen updating even for 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried turning the `ScreenUpdating` on just before the 2nd step and switching it back off after the 2nd step? Does it work? Is it still too slow for you?

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know why

Comment: See if this is what you like? Turn on `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and do this `Application.Visible = False` Set it back to true in the end.

Comment: Kool. That's Awesome :)